# How to build for Windows XP using WAF

Tags: windows-xp, waf

What needs to be done to build for Windows XP using the latest version of WAF and MSVC 2015? In the GUI, you can set the platform toolset to "Windows XP." Can this be done in the wscript?

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong? By default what you build with waf and MSVC will be compatible with XP. As long as you stick to parts of the Windows API that was available on XP. But that's up to you to ensure, not waf.